# How I open gmail directly from my application?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, gmail

I have this code:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
dialogIntent.setType("plain/text");
dialogIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

This opens a dialogue with DRIVE, GMAIL and SKYPE. I need to open gmail directly without the dialog appearing.

Already tried that and it does not work me. I'm doing this from a service.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your intent :

```
dialogIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity");
```

**Note:** this is not officially supported and may break in future versions. There is no documented or official way of launching the Gmail activity.

**Edit:** found another method, try and and see if it works:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
ResolveInfo best = null;
for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
  if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") ||
      info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail")) best = info;
if (best != null)
  intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
```

Comment: Already tried that and it does not work me, I'm doing this from a service

Comment: It probably won't work, and different versions of android muddy it further. Not to say it isn't a good answer, but as @whatissleep mentioned it isn't officially supported. You may not be able to do this at all.